# Apply alpha to texture at certain clipspace coordinates

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, textures, shader

This is not exactly the problem I have, but a simplified version of it. Say, I have a single image display at full screen size. I want to modify the alpha of this image, so that at the left-half (horizontally) of the screen, the alpha is 0.5 and at the right-half, alpha is 1. Just alpha 0.5 or 1, nothing else in between.

Here are my (failed) codes so far

This is my javascript codes to setup webgl

```
this.gl = canvas.getContext('webgl', {
    alpha: false,
});
this.gl.enable(this.gl.BLEND);
this.gl.blendFunc(this.gl.SRC_ALPHA, this.gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
this.gl.clearColor(1, 0, 0, 0); // red to highlight alpha problem
```

this is my vertex shader code

```
mediump float;
attribute vec2 coordinates;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;
varying float alpha;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(coordinates.x, coordinates.y, 1.0, 1.0);
    v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
    if (coordinates.x <= 0) {
        alpha = 0.5;
    } else {
        alpha = 1.0;
    }
}
```

and my fragment shader is standard simple

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
varying float alpha;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
void main() {
    vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord).rgba;
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

and at draw time

```
window.canvas.gl.clear(window.canvas.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
window.canvas.gl.useProgram(this.drawProgram);
window.canvas.gl.bindBuffer(window.canvas.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexBuffer);
window.canvas.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.positionLocation);
window.canvas.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.positionLocation, 2, window.canvas.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
window.canvas.gl.bindBuffer(window.canvas.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
window.canvas.gl.bindBuffer(window.canvas.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.texcoordBuffer);
window.canvas.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.texcoordLocation);
window.canvas.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.texcoordLocation, 2, window.canvas.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
window.canvas.gl.bindBuffer(window.canvas.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

window.canvas.gl.bindTexture(window.canvas.gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.texture);
window.canvas.gl.uniform1i(this.textureLocation, 0);
window.canvas.gl.drawArrays(window.canvas.gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

With these codes, I couldn't achieve what I want. First, the transparency does not start at the middle of the screen (clipspace x = 0), but at a seemingly random location. Also, there is gradual decline from alpha 1.0 to alpha 0.5, not the just the 2 values 0.5 and 1.0 I hope for. And I have no idea where this gradual transition comes from.

Obviously I am learning webgl so any pointer would be much appreciate. Any hint on how to solve the problem would be of great help to me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might find [these articles](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-how-it-works.html) helpful

Comment: Hello gman! Who wants to learn webgl but hasn't been to your site? :)) The 'red to highlight alpha problem' is taken straight from you. Thanks so much for all your great articles! But I guess I am just a bad student and skipped the part about vertices interpolating :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the transparency does not start at the middle of the screen [..]

because `alpha` is evaluated per vertex and interpolated for the fragments.

You have to do the evaluation per fragment rather than per vertex.

Pass `coordinates.x` or `gl_Position.x/gl_Position.w` from the vertex shader to the fragment shader:

```c
mediump float;
attribute vec2 coordinates;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;

varying vec2  v_texcoord;
varying vec2  pos;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(coordinates.xy, 1.0, 1.0);
    v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
    pos        = coordinates.xy;
}
```

Compute the alpha value in the fragment shader:

```c
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;
varying vec2 pos;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {
    vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord).rgba;
    float alpha = pos.x < 0.5 ? 0.5 : 1.0; 
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb, color.a * alpha);  
}
```

Note, the vertex shader is executed once for each vertex coordinate. The coordinates define the corners of the primitives. The fragment shader is executed for each fragment. The output parameters of the vertex shader are interpolated dependent on the position of the fragment on the primitive. The interpolated value is the input to the fragment shader.
If `alpha` is calculated in the vertex shader, then the `alpha` value for the fragments on the left is 0.5 and on the right it is 1.0. The fragments in between get an smoothly interpolated value int he range [0.5, 1.0].
The same happens to the position when it is passed from the vertex shader to the fragment shader. But since `alpha` is calculated in the fragment shader, the `alpha` value of each fragment is either 0.5 or 1.0, dependent on the interpolated value of `pos.x`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, as mentioned in the title, I would like to base on clip space coordinates, not texture coordinates. The problem above is just a simplified version and my original problem really depends on clip space coordinates. Sorry for not mention it again in the question itself. Please help if you know how to do this!

Comment: Buggy ok, so you've to pass the position from the vertex shader to the fragment shader. Calculate alpha per fragment rather than per vertex.

Comment: Thank you @Rabbid76! I followed your direction and got both the example and my original problem soved! Thumbs up! I accepted your answer.</br>However, if you have time, would you please explain why I failed before? I just calculated the alpha in the vertex shader, base on coordinates.x, then pass the alpha to the fragment shader. I didn't not assign it in the vertex, but still didn't achieve the desired result. Is it because coordinates.x (or even gl_Position.x / gl_Position.w) is not really in clip space yet?

Comment: @Buggy I tried to explain it in the answer. See the last part, which I've added right now.

Comment: @Rabbit76 Your answer now explained everything! Everything. Thanks so much for your patience and great help! Cheers!